# Populate data on change of form field in Extjs 4

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, extjs4

I am having 3 form fields in a window named as : studentId, StudentName, studentLastname. If I enter studentID, it should populate values of studentname and studentlastname. How can I do that? I know that, I have to use listeners, but I am not sure, how exactly I will load values from database for this. It should be AJAx request and not form submission/reload.

Please let me know if u know it. I am using Extjs 4 and Spring MVC.

Thanks.
Jm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far should the answer go? Do you also expect the server side code?

On the most basic level, you'd need to define a [model](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) with a [proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy):

```
Ext.define('Student', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'students'
    }
});
```

Then once you enter a studentId you can do:

```
var iStudent = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('Student');

iStudent.load( studendId, {
    success: function( aStudent ) {
        console.log( aStudent );
        // Feed the student details into the form.
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't need any information regarding server side code. I just want to know Extjs code. I gave information regarding my frameworks, so that, u might get idea what exactly I use. Thanks for your information, I will try and let u know here.. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Ext is functionally rich and provides more than one way to do what you want. If you are not prepared to take the time to learn how it works you are better off sticking to JQuery or another of the DOM manipulators, or maybe even raw javascript and http requests.

Everything you need to know is in the API docs on the [Sencha Website](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api) there are lots of examples and guides and a pretty good forum. But there is a lot to learn.

There is little information there about server side code, it is not Sencha's job to teach you Spring. Your server needs to be able to accept a request and return with a simple '{success=true}' response or data in a format that Ext can use. eg. XML or JSON. There is also a DIRECT API but I don't recommend it for your first app.

Let's say you want to use a JSON string, your server response would be something like this

```
[{"studentId":12345,"studentFirstName":"John","studentLastName":"Smith"},
{"studentId":12346,"studentFirstName":"Jenny","studentLastName":"Brown"},
{"studentId":12347,"studentFirstName":"Able","studentLastName":"Seaman"}]
```

You use this to populate an Ext.Store via an Ext.Proxy and Ext.Model (see lzhaki's answer)

Your text boxes are available to you through the Ext.ComponentManager and you can use the methods provided by your Ext.Component(s) to execute methods like .setValue()

When you start out Ext can be hard work, it goes well beyond DOM manipulation and you need to understand how it works to get the value it provides to the programmer and your app maintainability.